# Strawberry Perl: "out of memory!"

Tags: perl, memory

trying to run the following code:

```
$combs = combinations(\@set,$k);
while (my $c = $combs->next)
{
        $nrc=1;
}
```

Gives me "out of memory!" when I hit Ctrl+C (because its taking too long and it should not) if I pass a set from, for example, (0..450) and numbers to combine ($k) of 6. This issue does not occur with, lets say, a set of 0..45 and $k=6.

Note that the while loop seems to do nothing, in the original script it printed out the combination and incremented a counter that will hold the total number of combinations. But since I was not sure what the problem was, I decided to eliminate that.
I've read the Algorithm:Combinatorics on CPAN and it states that memory usage is minimal, so I don't know what's happening.

I am using Strawberry Perl 32bit on a Windows 10 machine.

Thanks.

--------------------- COMPLETE CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use List::MoreUtils "uniq";
use Algorithm::Combinatorics "combinations";

my $argc = $#ARGV+1;
my @set;

if ($argc == 0)
{
    print STDERR "Valor minimo de rango: "; # range min
    my $minrange = int <STDIN>;
    print STDERR "Valor maximo de rango: "; #range max
    my $maxrange = int <STDIN>;

    @set = uniq sort { $a <=> $b }($minrange...$maxrange);
}
elsif ($argc == 1)
{
    open(SETFROMFILE,"<$ARGV[0]") or die "No se puedo abrir el fichero, $!";
    chomp(@set = <SETFROMFILE>);
    close(SETFROMFILE);
    @set = uniq sort { $a <=> $b } @set;
}
else
{
    print STDERR "Uso: $0 [file]\n";
    exit;
}

my $nrc = 0;

print STDERR "\n";
print STDERR "Numeros a combinar: "; # get subset
my $k = <STDIN>;

if ($k == 0) { exit; }

$combs = combinations(\@set,$k);

print STDERR "\n";

while (my $c = $combs->next)
{
    print join(";",@$c) . "\n";
    $nrc++;
}

print STDERR "\n";
print STDERR "numero total de combinaciones: $nrc\n";
```

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't compile, which makes me wonder what your actual code looks like. Can you please post the exact code you're using?

Comment: Sure. I didn't because that's the part that matters because its the only that do (in its original version) something useful. Plus, I speak spanish so some printfs are in spanish. It maybe doesn't run because it lacks the 

use Algorithm::Combinatorics "combinations";

but I will post it though.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot done

Comment: Thanks for adding that. Don't worry about the Spanish, we're all fluent in Perl :) How are you running this when you get the out of memory error? Are you passing a filename or min and max values? If a file, how many lines, and what is the file size? If min/max, what are the values?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot using min max just for testing pourposes. The values are min = 0, max = 450. The program just shows a blinking prompt since I removed the print statement that prints the combination and only left a counter $nrc++ to avoid the overhead in printing. But I left the program running for hours and it keeps going, I know they are a lot of combinations, but I thought it wouldnt take so long, then I hit Ctrl+C to stop it and I get "Out of memory!" So I thought that actually the program crashed at some point and thats why it took so long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw( combinations );

sub show_mem { system('ps', '--no-heading', '-o', 'rss', $$); }

my @set = (0..450);
my $k = 6;

my $count = 0;
#show_mem();
my $combs = combinations(\@set, $k);
#show_mem();
while (my $c = $combs->next) {
   ++$count;
   if (($count % 100_000) == 0) {
      print("$count\n");
      #show_mem();
   }
}
```

Output:

```
  784
  784
100000
  776
200000
  784
300000
  788
400000
  776
500000
  780
600000
  784
700000
  768
800000
  784
900000
  784
1000000
  776
...
```

Of course, it will take *forever* to go through all C(451, 6) = 11,303,769,578,640 combinations! (We're talking about 251 days on my machine<sup>[1]</sup>.)

(Note that 11,303,769,578,640 is too large for a 32-bit integer. Fortunately, Perl will switching to using a double-precision floating-point number, and those are large enough to hold that all numbers up to and including that one.)

---

By the way, if you just need the number of combinations, you can use

```
my $count = 1;  $count *= ( @set - $_ + 1 ) / $_ for 1..$k;
```

---

1. How I timed it:

   ```
   use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw( combinations );
   use Time::HiRes              qw( time );

   my @set = (0..450);
   my $k = 6;

   my $count = 0;
   my $combs = combinations(\@set, $k);
   my $s = time;
   while (my $c = $combs->next) {
      ++$count;
      last if $count == 1_000_000;
   }
   my $e = time;
   print($e-$s, "\n");
   ```

Comment: That's the thing! it should work because combinatorics as far as I read iterates over (like reading a file line by line) but I am pretty new at perl and not much of programming though. But as far as I got it should run, that's why I made clear I am running strawberry Perl 32bits on Windows. Because when I searched for solutions the most recurrent stuff was something called "ulimits" which is a bash thing I guess, but I don't have that on Windows, so not sure if that's the problem or not.

Comment: How do you know it's not doing anything? It will take 251 days to run on my machine. Did you check if your loop was entered by adding a print statement like I did? What's the size of the `perl` process in Task Manager? More specifically, is it growing?  (Small changes in the size are irrelevant, I'm talking long term trend.) Right now, we have one demonstration of it working, and no demonstration of it not working, so I consider the matter closed unless that changes.

Comment: because if I add a print statement to print the combinations it does, however, to make it process faster I removed the print statement and left only a counter, so when the program is executing I see only a blinking prompt, but after some hours I think it might have stopped and when I hit Ctrl+C it says "Out of memory!"

Comment: Also, how do you estimate that running time?

Comment: I timed how long it took to find the first 1,000,000 combinations, then I extrapolated for 11,303,769,578,640. Added code to answer.

Comment: Also, As I said, I can't be really sure why the "out of memory!" since I deleted the print statement because, for example, when using set 0..45 and K=20, if I leave only a counter, I get the number of combinations in less than 1 minute. But with printing I started running it 3 minutes ago and it's still going. So I am not sure that if I try it with 0..450 with printing will seem like it works ok but only because it goes slower, so basically I will have to wait 251 days to find out, lol.

Its done now and it took 5 minutes vs less than 1 minute.

Comment: Perl is 2.6 MB on task manager and 31% CPU usage. All steady.

Comment: Don't know why it said out of memory -- Ctrl-C in XS code gone wrong? -- but that's not the problem (as you can see in Task Manager). The problem is that the work is taking a long time, but that's too be expected given what you asked it to do. If all you want is the count, I added code to my answer that completes in microseconds.

Comment: No, no. I want the possible combinations for other pourposes (to perform other actions on them), but just don't care about printing them, the counter is just to add something that doesn't require heavy computation but also allows me to see if the program is doing anything or not.

Comment: You're going to need to parallelize if you want to complete this in a much shorter time frame.

Comment: How can I do that ? And how much shorter?. Yes, maybe the "out of memory!" isnt actually a "out of memory" and it just said that.
I thought the problem was because I am running it on Windows and its Strawberry Perl, since after I googled it people talked about checking ulimit and other things (I even downloaded a program called editbin and set a /LARGEADDRESSAWARE flag) to see if it helped but no.

Comment: Re "*How can I do that?*", You need to start with an algorithm that can be parallelized. /// Re "*And how much shorter?*", As short as you want. The more processors you add, the faster it will be.

Comment: The Ctrl-C probably resulted in some pointer being NULL, which was incorrectly interpreted as a memory allocation error. Again, not important.

Comment: I don't know, thats what other people said when others consulted on "out of memory!" they said "check ulimit" "Generally speaking, when I've had that problem, it was that there was a memory limit via ulimit - removing that limit 'solved' the problem. "

Comment: Thanks for your help ikegami, you are really knowledgeable.

Answer (score -2):

There are *11.1 trillion* combinations of six items out of 450. I'm not surprised it ran out of memory!

Comment: Algorithm:combinatorics says you should be careful of not using it in a list context because that way you will be storing everything, but use it in the scalar context and use the iterator as it is in the example code above.

Comment: reply moved to other comment